# how to reference imagesearch.dll to c# winforms?

Tags: c#, if-statement, dll, unmanaged

I can't reference ImageSearch.dll in my project. I've been trying for days and can't get any further. it seems to me that i'm the only one with this problem and i don't know what to do next. Is it possible to reference a .dll manually, for example via lines of code? It's nerve wracking and need this or a similar feature.

**I keep getting the following error:**

*Could not add a reference to imagesearch.dll. Make sure the file is accessible and is a valid assembly or COM component.*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw4iU.jpg)

Hope someone can help me...

Comment: Your question isn't about assembly language, like `mov eax, [rdi]`.  Stop editing the wrong tags onto it after other users fix your tags.

Answer (score 1):

That message is telling you that the dll you're trying to reference is something that .NET doesn't know how to work with automatically. This means it has no idea what functions are in the dll or how they work. So, if a dll isn't a .NET assembly or exposed via COM, then you can use PInvoke (Platform Invoke).

Don't add the dll as a reference to your project at all, instead add it as a content file that gets output with the rest of your compiled code. Getting PInvoke to work with an arbitrary DLL can be quite complicated, so be prepared for some headaches. There's an entire website with examples of how to pinvoke for all sorts of libraries at http://pinvoke.net/ that will give you lots of ideas.

Then you can call methods in the dll by doing something like:

```
// Import ImageSearch.dll (containing the function we need) and define
// the method corresponding to the native function.
[DllImport("ImageSearch.dll"]
private static extern int FindImage(string imagePath);
```

Obviously I have no idea what imagesearch.dll is or does, so I have no idea what the actual PInvoke function should look like, you'll have to figure that out from the dll's interface.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke